# php html table pivot column header

Tags: php, html-table

I am close of reaching my desired output, but I have this problem..

[image]

The column header must be 1,2,3,4,5 etc. etc. and here is my code so far..

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
                            <tr bgcolor="#009933">
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Date</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Date</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Date</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Date</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Date</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $queryres = mysql_query("SELECT stud_name,
                            MAX(IF(date = '1', remark, '')) AS '1',
                            MAX(IF(date = '2', remark, '')) AS '2',
                            MAX(IF(date = '3', remark, '')) AS '3',
                            MAX(IF(date = '4', remark, '')) AS '4',
                            MAX(IF(date = '5', remark, '')) AS '5',
                            MAX(IF(date = '6', remark, '')) AS '6',
                            MAX(IF(date = '7', remark, '')) AS '7',
                            MAX(IF(date = '8', remark, '')) AS '8',
                            MAX(IF(date = '9', remark, '')) AS '9',
                            MAX(IF(date = '10', remark, '')) AS '10',
                            MAX(IF(date = '11', remark, '')) AS '11',
                            MAX(IF(date = '12', remark, '')) AS '12',
                            MAX(IF(date = '13', remark, '')) AS '13',
                            MAX(IF(date = '14', remark, '')) AS '14',
                            MAX(IF(date = '15', remark, '')) AS '15',
                            MAX(IF(date = '16', remark, '')) AS '16',
                            MAX(IF(date = '17', remark, '')) AS '17',
                            MAX(IF(date = '18', remark, '')) AS '18',
                            MAX(IF(date = '19', remark, '')) AS '19',
                            MAX(IF(date = '20', remark, '')) AS '20', 
                            MAX(IF(date = '21', remark, '')) AS '21',
                            MAX(IF(date = '22', remark, '')) AS '22',
                            MAX(IF(date = '23', remark, '')) AS '23',
                            MAX(IF(date = '24', remark, '')) AS '24',
                            MAX(IF(date = '25', remark, '')) AS '25',
                            MAX(IF(date = '26', remark, '')) AS '26',
                            MAX(IF(date = '27', remark, '')) AS '27',
                            MAX(IF(date = '28', remark, '')) AS '28',
                            MAX(IF(date = '29', remark, '')) AS '29',
                            MAX(IF(date = '30', remark, '')) AS '30',
                            MAX(IF(date = '31', remark, '')) AS '31'
                            FROM tb_attendance WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND description = '$desc'
                            GROUP BY stud_name");
                            while($result= mysql_fetch_array($queryres)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['stud_name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['1']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['2']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['3']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['4']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['5']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
                            }
?>
</table>
```

Is there a way to change (DATE) into the numbers (1,2,3,4,5) and only show the numbers where there is a record(remark = Present or Absent).
for example 1 2 3 have a records but 4 5 has nothing so 1 2 3 must only be shown in the table

Comment: What's the `Remark` column for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do another query to find out which dates have values in the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr bgcolor="#009933">
    <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
<?php
$queryres = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date 
                         FROM tb_attendance 
                         WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND description = '$desc' 
                         ORDER BY date");
$dates = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryres)) {
    $dates[] = $row['date']; // Remember which date columns have values, so we only display those in the student rows.
    echo '<td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
}
?>
<td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
</tr>
<?php
$queryres = mysql_query("
    SELECT stud_name,
        MAX(IF(date = '1', remark, '')) AS '1',
        MAX(IF(date = '2', remark, '')) AS '2',
        MAX(IF(date = '3', remark, '')) AS '3',
        MAX(IF(date = '4', remark, '')) AS '4',
        MAX(IF(date = '5', remark, '')) AS '5',
        MAX(IF(date = '6', remark, '')) AS '6',
        MAX(IF(date = '7', remark, '')) AS '7',
        MAX(IF(date = '8', remark, '')) AS '8',
        MAX(IF(date = '9', remark, '')) AS '9',
        MAX(IF(date = '10', remark, '')) AS '10',
        MAX(IF(date = '11', remark, '')) AS '11',
        MAX(IF(date = '12', remark, '')) AS '12',
        MAX(IF(date = '13', remark, '')) AS '13',
        MAX(IF(date = '14', remark, '')) AS '14',
        MAX(IF(date = '15', remark, '')) AS '15',
        MAX(IF(date = '16', remark, '')) AS '16',
        MAX(IF(date = '17', remark, '')) AS '17',
        MAX(IF(date = '18', remark, '')) AS '18',
        MAX(IF(date = '19', remark, '')) AS '19',
        MAX(IF(date = '20', remark, '')) AS '20', 
        MAX(IF(date = '21', remark, '')) AS '21',
        MAX(IF(date = '22', remark, '')) AS '22',
        MAX(IF(date = '23', remark, '')) AS '23',
        MAX(IF(date = '24', remark, '')) AS '24',
        MAX(IF(date = '25', remark, '')) AS '25',
        MAX(IF(date = '26', remark, '')) AS '26',
        MAX(IF(date = '27', remark, '')) AS '27',
        MAX(IF(date = '28', remark, '')) AS '28',
        MAX(IF(date = '29', remark, '')) AS '29',
        MAX(IF(date = '30', remark, '')) AS '30',
        MAX(IF(date = '31', remark, '')) AS '31'
    FROM tb_attendance WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND description = '$desc'
    GROUP BY stud_name");
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($queryres)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result['stud_name']."</td>";
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">".$result[$date]."</td>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question sir, how I can join another table in tb_attendance, its confusing because of the long query XD

Comment: Just add a `JOIN` clause before the `WHERE` clause, and add the columns you want to get from the second table to the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: sir please check this coz I've already played around with it and this is one of the code I've done --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_01juH1v0fDQ2l4YW1BU0xPMk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have `tb_attendance.` at the end of the `SELECT` line. You need a column name after the `.`.

Comment: what about the date and remark inside MAX do I need to add tb_attendance. ?

Comment: Only if there's a column with the same name in the other table.

Comment: uhmmm sir my query has no error anymore but the table is not sorted in asc https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_01juH1v0fDZEFOWXJESmI3akU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you need to write a new question. Post the updated query, some sample data, and the desired result. Make a sqlfiddle instead of a google doc, so we can execute the query with the data.